# Variables not available in injected Javascript in iOS WKWebView

Tags: ios, youtube-api, wkwebview

I am trying to use the Youtube iframe API in my WKWebView in iOS but am not able to use the `player` object for calling `pauseVideo()` etc. functions.

My `WKWebView` instance is calling its `loadHTMLString(string:, baseURL)` function using the following script

```
<iframe id="test-iframe" enablejsapi=true width="854" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-hLoU2qP4zc?autoplay=1&amp;start=0&amp;rel=0">
<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('test-iframe');
}
```

then later after the webview has loaded and user has spent good time interacting with the webview the following call is made to pause the video

```
script = """
player.pauseVideo();
"""
webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { res, err in
    print("completion of JS eval", res, err)
}
```

This raises exception:

```
completion of JS eval nil Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=ReferenceError: Can't find variable: player, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=11, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=https://www.youtube.com/, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred})
```

I am not sure what is causing `player` to be unavailable.
Digging deeper I realised that no variable at all are available to the injected code as I tried to declare only this in my script and still failed make it available in my injected code.

Loaded this script using `loadHTMLString(string:, baseURL)`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var testContent = 'test content';
</script>
```

Then injected script:

```
script = """
  window.webkit.messageHandlers.handler.postMessage(testContent.toString());
"""
webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { res, err in
    print("completion of JS eval", res, err)
}
```

Still gives me the error (removed other messages in error): `Can't find variable: testContent`

I am trying to understand what could be reason behind this issue of unavailable variables in injected scripts

Comment: is there a closing script tag in your web view?
is it possible to define player within the injected script as a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WKNavigationDelegate`

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //... assuming the `webView` is setup here
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        //...
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#212121';", completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
}
```